# How to replace multiple different chars with white space?

Tags: c#, string, replace

How to replace different/multiple chars with white space for each instance of character?

characters to be replaced are `\ / : * ? < > |`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with string.Split and string.Join:

```
string myString = string.Join(" ", input.Split(@"\/:*?<>|".ToCharArray()));
```

Out of curiousity tested this for performance, and it is considerably faster than the Regex approach.

Comment: +1 for originality and an approach I started out with but didn't conclude (and for showing me `string.Join` instead of `Split(..).Join()`) :)

Comment: the funny thing about this answer is that depending on which you are more familiar with, this could be more/less readable than RegEx.  But for me, RegEx is more readable.

Comment: According to Jon Skeet's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1280227/52277 performance depends on input format

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex.Replace(@"my \ special / : string", @"[\\/:*?<>|]", " ");
```

I might have some of the escapes wrong... :/

Comment: Unfortunately, they are wrong and it won't compile. I think you mean this: `Regex.Replace(@"my \ ?? special / : string", @"[\\/:\*?<>|]", " ");` (note that `\?` etc is allowed, but not necessary in a character class)

Answer (score 1):

`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, @"[\\/:*?<>|]", " ")`

Comment: actually I think you mean. @"[\\/:*\?\<\>\|]", because many of those characters are Reg Ex control characters.

Comment: Regex control characters are not regex control characters inside a character class, with the exception of `-`, `[` and `\\`.

Comment: You're right, I should've thought about character escapes a bit more. I've edited to something I do think is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [String API methods in C#.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(VS.85).aspx)

String.replace would work, if you called it seven times.
Or String.indexOfAny in a loop, using String.remove and String.insert.

Going the efficient lines of code way, Regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compilable piece of code:

```
// input
string input = @"my \ ?? spe<<||>>cial / : string";

// regex
string test = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\\/:*?<>|]", " ");

// test now contains "my      spe      cial     string"
```

Note: this post is a fix of the original JustLoren's code, it's not entirely mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Regex

```
static void Main(string[] args)       
{        
    string myStr = @"\ / : * ? < > |";
    Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"\\|\/|\:|\*|\?|\<|\>|\|");
    string replaced = myRegex.Replace(myStr, new MatchEvaluator(OnMatch));
    Console.WriteLine(replaced);    
}

private static string OnMatch(Match match)
{
    return " ";
}
```

Comment: when posting code, indent it with four spaces (or click the Code button) to get it correctly colored and laid out.