# Get first 250 words of a string?

Tags: c#, string

How do I get the first 250 words of a string?

Comment: `str.Split().Take(250)`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: By splitting the string with spaces

Comment: I don't understand why questions like these get mercilessly downvoted and closed... there was a time when many of us couldn't figure this out either. Also notice he's asking for _words_, not characters.

Comment: @kprobst hopefully the rest of us put some minimal effort into figuring it out though

Comment: @kprobst:  Even when we couldn't figure out basic things (and I'm struggling as a new python user at the moment), we could still cover the basics in a question:  What have I tried?  What was the result vs. what I expected to happen?  What specific part am I getting hung up on?

Comment: @Blorgbeard He said _words_, not characters. I'm guessing people jumped on this because of that.

Comment: @kprobst no-one appears to think he meant characters..

Comment: i'm not going to vote on this one.  the question is a little big vague, but it's certainly a whole lot easier to understand than some other questions on this site.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to split the string. You can use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) without parameter(whitespaces are assumed).

```
IEnumerable<string> words = str.Split().Take(250);
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq` for `Enumerable.Take`.

You can use `ToList()` or `ToArray()` ro create a new collection from the query or save memory and enumerate it directly:

```
foreach(string word in words)
    Console.WriteLine(word);
```

---

**Update**

Since it seems to be quite popular I'm adding following extension which is more efficient than the `Enumerable.Take` approach and also returns a collection instead of the (deferred executed) *query*.

It uses `String.Split` where [white-space characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are assumed to be the delimiters  if the separator parameter is null or contains no characters. But the method also allows to pass different delimiters:

```
public static string[] GetWords(
       this string input,
       int count = -1,
       string[] wordDelimiter = null,
       StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.None)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return new string[] { };

    if(count < 0)
        return input.Split(wordDelimiter, options);

    string[] words = input.Split(wordDelimiter, count + 1, options);
    if (words.Length <= count)
        return words;   // not so many words found

    // remove last "word" since that contains the rest of the string
    Array.Resize(ref words, words.Length - 1);

    return words;
}
```

It can be used easily:

```
string str = "A B C   D E F";
string[] words = str.GetWords(5, null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // A,B,C,D,E
```

Comment: "If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters."

Comment: +1... Also if the question would be real some searching for space/whitespace/separators would be more appropriate (like "\w+\s"), possibly combined with `yield return` to not read outside first 250 words.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Note that the `Split` without arguments is not the same as `Split(' ')`. It uses [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx) internally which includes multiple characters.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: since it's grew in populairy i've added another approach which is more efficient and allows to pass different delimiters than white-spaces. It also reads only until it has the desired word-count due to [this `String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131450(v=vs.110).aspx)-overload.

Answer (score 9):

```
yourString.Split(' ').Take(250);
```

I guess. You should provide more info.

Comment: Why do you create a new list from the array before you take 250?

Comment: I'd use take before ToList to take advantage of IEnumerable's lazy evaluation

Comment: @TimSchmelter Tiping from memory. I wasn't sure if Array was IEnumerable. It wasn't some c# versions ago. Editing. Thanks.

Comment: +0... Array.ToList is way overkill. @BlackBear, there is no lazy evaluation - Split returns array.

Answer (score 5):

String.Join(" ", yourstring.Split().Take(250).ToArray())

Answer (score 1):

Addition to Tim answer, this is what you can try

```
IEnumerable<string> words = str.Split().Take(250);
StringBuilder firstwords = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string s in words)
{
   firstwords.Append(s + " ");
}
firstwords.Append("...");
Console.WriteLine(firstwords.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public string TakeWords(string str,int wordCount)
{
    char lastChar='\0';
    int spaceFound=0;
    var strLen= str.Length;
    int i=0;
    for(; i<strLen; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==' ' && lastChar!=' ')
        {
            spaceFound++;
        }
        lastChar=str[i];
        if(spaceFound==wordCount)
            break;
    }
    return str.Substring(0,i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible without calling Take().

```
string[] separatedWords = stringToProcess.Split(new char[] {' '}, 250, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Which also allows splitting based on more than just space " " and therefore fixes occurrences when spaces are incorrectly missing in input.

```
string[] separatedWords = stringToProcess.Split(new char[] {' ', '.', ',' ':', ';'}, 250, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Use `StringSplitOptions.None`, if you want empty strings to be returned instead.