# Remove extra commas in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a string like "abc,,bcd,";

The output should be abc,bcd i.e. the extra commas should be removed.

Help needed

Comment: Does the string contain substrings like ", ," ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, ",+", ",").Trim(',');
```

Comment: Nice, wanted to tell you that you were missing the trailing Trim(','). But I see you fixed it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
string s = "abc,,bcd,";
s = s.Trim(',');
while (s.Contains(",,"))
    s = s.Replace(",,", ",");
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that this approach can be dangerous in some cases (leading to infinite loop). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279859/how-to-replace-multiple-white-spaces-with-one-white-space/1279900#1279900

Comment: Lets hope that the asian comma is not to different to the english one X-)

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "abc,,bcd,";
string output = String.Join(",",
    input.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting the string into an array.
Then loop through the array.
Check if the current element has a value you find acceptable.
Append that value to a stringbuilder.
If that is not the last element of the array, append a comma to the stringbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "abc,,bcd,";

input.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);
```

Comment: Simply use `string.Join` instead of `Aggregate`. It's more readable, and faster (concats all at once).