# How to remove spaces from string?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string value

```
string text = "-----------------\r\n      Some text here      Some text here\r\n"
```

Is there a way to remove 2 spaces in each place where are many spaces?
Thank you, for your help

Comment: What ouptput do you want?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 2 spaces ?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c

Comment: I guess you could split it up and then join the parts as per your needed space constraints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex.

```
var result = new Regex("\s{2,}").Replace(text,constForWhiteSpace)
```

Comment: this can be slow, though, depending on how many strings you need to do this on.

Comment: Sure, consider this like "general purpose" answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. OP said they want to remove two whitespaces but this removes all whitespaces.

Comment: Then ',' can be removed. Anyway when you have the basic idea, you can change the details.

Comment: The issue is that your `Replace` method is incorrect.

Comment: this would return `a.bc` for `a.b..c` (replace `.` with blank)

Comment: @I4V you are right. should be some const fot whitespace instead of string.Empty

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
text = text.Replace("   "," ");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}");    // Regex to match more than two occurences of space 
text = regex.Replace(text, @"");
```

Comment: this would return `a.bc` for `a.b..c` (replace `.` with blank)

Answer (score 1):

edit: this is for speed, otherwise regex as suggested by other answers is fine. This function is very fast.

edit 2: just remove \r \n if you want to keep new lines.

```
        public static String SingleSpacedTrim(String inString)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Boolean inBlanks = false;
            foreach (Char c in inString)
            {
                switch (c)
                {
                    case '\r':
                    case '\n':
                    case '\t':
                    case ' ':
                        if (!inBlanks)
                        {
                            inBlanks = true;
                            sb.Append(' ');
                        }   
                        continue;
                    default:
                        inBlanks = false;
                        sb.Append(c);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString().Trim();
        }
```

Comment: This collapses white space into a single space character? Or what does it do?

Comment: @dtb yes, that's exactly what it does

Answer (score 1):

Try it....

```
   string _str = "-----------------\r\n      Some text here      Some text here\r\n";
    _str = _str.Trim();
    Console.WriteLine(_str.Replace(" ",""));
```

Output : 
SometexthereSometexthere

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many spaces there are, you could use

```
text.Replace("       ", "     ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = new Regex("\s{2,}").Replace(text,string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dirty = "asdjk    asldkjas dasdl l aksdjal;sd            asd;lkjdaslj";

var clean = string.Join(" ", dirty.Split(' ').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like Regex or the text is large you can use this extension:

```
public static String TrimBetween(this string text, int maxWhiteSpaces = 1)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    foreach (Char c in text)
    {
        if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            count = 0;
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        else
        {
            if (++count <= maxWhiteSpaces)
                sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then it's simple as:

```
string text = "-----------------\r\n      Some text here      Some text here\r\n";
text = text.TrimBetween(2);
```

Result:

```
-----------------
Some text here  Some text here
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the nicest piece of code but this should remove two whitespaces from the text if you want to use a regex.

```
//one.two..three...four....five..... (dots = spaces)
string input = "one two  three   four    five     ";

string result = new Regex(@"\s{2,}").Replace(input, delegate(Match m)
{    
    if (m.Value.Length > 2)
    {    
        int substring = m.Value.Length - 2;
        //if there are two spaces, just remove the one
        if (m.Value.Length == 2) substring = 1;

        string str = m.Value.Substring(m.Value.Length - substring);
        return str;
    }
    return m.Value;
});
```

Output would be

```
//dots represent spaces. Two spaces are removed from each one but one 
//unless there are two spaces, in which case only one is removed.
one.two.three.four..five...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use String.Replace function:

```
text=text.Replace("      ","  ");
```

But remember you are supposed to research a bit your request before posting: this is very basic stuff.

Comment: Why is he receiveing negavite vote? I used this method too and it works! Easy, simple, and working!