# how to replace one/multiple spaces into a deliminator using C#

Tags: c#, regex

Now I'm parsing a text, I want to split and add one by one

But first thing first, the best way is to replace multiple spaces with one unique deliminator

Below is the sample target text:

```
                        Total fare                         619,999.0d-
      12 11 82139     09/13/2013 D              103,500.00  2/025189 PARK LA000137
                      09/13/2013 D              50.00 File Ticket - PS1309121018882/
```

Can anybody know how to handle it in C#?

Comment: Is that the sample code or string where space needs to be replaced?

Comment: @hima this is definitely not a sample code :)

Comment: What do you want to do with single space ? can you show target string with a source string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1279859/284240

Comment: @Jerry: I overlooked it. I should have asked sample source text or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the best way is to replace multiple spaces with one unique
>   deliminator

Not really sure if its the best way, but following works, without REGEX

```
string newStr = string.Join(":", 
                str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: That does work, thank you for helping me and make it a better place!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var strings = text.Split(' ').Where(str => str.Length > 0);
```

Comment: `String.Split` has a `(String[], StringSplitOptions)` overload that accepts `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
string delimiter = ":";
var whiteSpaceNormalised = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", delimiter);
```

Comment: \s also matches new line.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions instead, replace more than one occurrence of space with single space

```
string parsedText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputString,"[ ]+"," ");
```