# Replacing multiple spaces into just one?

Tags: vb.net

Okay, so I am working on this VB.NET program and I have tried using the .replace() to do this but it's not the best way to do this. I have a string with multiple spaces in between data which I don't want, what would be the best way to strip the spaces from the string but 1?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match multiple spaces and replace with a single space:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, " {2,}", " ")
```

Comment: Neat! It works perfectly thank you, all the other code I just found on other threads happens to be really big and bulky which I don't want, this works perfectly, and sorry for the duplicate!

Comment: @Guffa, can you please explain the pattern that you used.

Comment: @MansoorShaikh: It's just a space followed by the quantifier `{2,}`, so it matches a space, repeated two or more times.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way using arrays, in case you'd prefer to avoid regular expressions.

Given this starting string:

```
Dim str As String = "This   is a test      string"
```

You can do this:

```
Dim arr As String() = str.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim compressedSpaces As String = String.Join(" ", arr)
```

You can also combine it onto one line:

```
Dim newString As String = String.Join(" ", str.Split({" "c}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

Comment: From the answer cited by @TimSchmelter, the RegEx option is faster. Jon Skeet says this approach could create a ton of work for the garbage collector, depending on how long the source string is.

Comment: RegEx is rarely faster in my experience. Best to check under load if speed is a factor. IMO Regex should be avoided due to debug/maintainability issues.

Comment: The RegEx solution is faster in this case. See the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1280227/645511  I should note that it is very close, depending on the details of exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't doubt it is faster - I wouldn't use it anyway. (One+ too many times trying to reversing engineer RegEx to find other folks  problems.)

Comment: Honestly, that is one of the reasons I took the time to answer this question. I knew the likely answers would center around use of RegEx, and sometimes I *do* use them, but if an easy answer is available that avoids them without causing too many problems, I would lean towards that instead.