# How can you trimend of textbox text from another textbox text

Tags: c#, string, trim

I have two textbox's textbox1 (read/write) & textbox2 (read only), textbox1 is where you enter text at which point you press a button to pass that text into textbox2 (textbox2 continually concatenates the text from textbox1). I have a second button that I want to press to remove the text from textbox2 that is still in textbox1. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

I was thinking;

```
string one = textbox1.text;
string two = textbox2.text;
string newTwo = two.trimend( value of string 'one' needs to be removed );
textbox2.text = newTwo;

textbox1;
world

textbox2;
hello world
```

I know this sounds odd but it's a bit of  a work around for an algebra calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If (textbox2.Text.EndsWith(textbox1.Text))
    textbox2.Text = textbox2.Text.Substring(0, textbox2.Text.Length - textbox1.Text.Length);
```

Comment: Cheers, didn't see that. I've always hovered my mouse over the up down arrows and it's told me my reputation isn't high enough. Just realised I could click the tick to accept the answer...

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
var start = two.IndexOf(one);
textbox2.text = two.Substring(start);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Replace` method

```
string newTwo = two.Replace(one,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i undestand your question boils down to "How to implement `TrimEnd`?". You can use code like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TrimEnd(this string str,
                                 string subject,
                                 StringComparison stringComparison)
    {
        var lastIndexOfSubject = str.LastIndexOf(subject, stringComparison);
        return (lastIndexOfSubject == -1
                || (str.Length - lastIndexOfSubject) > subject.Length)
            ? str
            : str.Substring(0, lastIndexOfSubject);
    }
}
```

Then is your code-behind:

```
textbox2.text = textbox2.text.TrimEnd(textbox1.text, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: @serdar's implementation is much more better then mine :)

Answer (score 0):

@jayvee is right. Replacing with `string.Empty` would do.

But there's one problem with that:

When replacing `"Hello"` in `"Hello World"` the leading whitespace would remain. `newTwo` would be `" World"`. You may also would want to replace multiple whitespaces via `Regex` as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279859/how-to-replace-multiple-white-spaces-with-one-white-space) and then `Trim()` the new string.

Also this is case sensitive.