# remove two or more empty between space in word

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to replace any space between in word in with dash in `C#`. But my problem is when I want remove space in sample string like this:

```
"a  b"
```

or

```
"a    b"
```

When I try this, I get this result:

`"a--b"` and `"a---b"`

How can I put one dash for any count of space between the word?

Like this:

`"a          b"`

`"a-b"`

Comment: How are you doing it? Whats your code? `string.Replace`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use like below

```
string xyz = "1   2   3   4   5";
xyz = string.Join( "-", xyz.Split( new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ));
```

Reference

1. [How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)
2. [How to replace multiple white spaces with one white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279859/how-to-replace-multiple-white-spaces-with-one-white-space)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) here.

```
Regex.Replace("a    b", @"\s+", "-");
```

**\s** looks for a `space` and **+** counts for spaces, if one or more spaces found sequentially. The pattern will be matched and replaced.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with many approaches. using Regular Expressions:

```
    string a = "a         b   c de";
    string b = Regex.Replace(a, "\\s+", "-");
```

Or if you dont want to use Regex, Here's a function which will take a string and the character to replace as arguments and return the formatted string.

```
    public string ReplaceWhitespaceWithChar(string input,char ch)
    {
        string temp = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {

            if (input[i] != ' ')
            {
                temp += input[i];
            }
            else if (input[i] == ' ' && input[i + 1] != ' ')
            {
                temp += ch;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for your requirement

```
        string tags = "This           sample";
        string cleanedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(tags, @"\s+", "-");

        Response.Write(cleanedString);
```

And result will be :

```
"This-sample"
```

I hope it will work for you.