# Split text in group of "x" characters vb.net

Tags: vb.net, split

I need to split some text, but i'm having trouble with some extra spaces.
The following image shows the usual output text.

[image: example]

I want to add the split values in a checkedlistbox and i have the following code:

```
Dim SEPARATED = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCr, vbLf, vbTab, ">") '" "C

    CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each item In separated
        If item <> "" Then CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove("#")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove("PI")

    Dim MODIFIED As String() = ANSWER.ToString.Split(" ")
```

buuuuuuut the extra spaces are giving me headaches. I don't know how to split the text in groups of twelve chars ( they're always 12, the spaces complete them) .

In conclusion, using the example, i want to only show "DEFAULT","EX W SPACE","POTATO" and "HELP PLS".

Thank you !

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279859/how-to-replace-multiple-white-spaces-with-one-white-space

Comment: You could replace the periods with single spaces.

Comment: @MichaelZ. : The periods doesn't exist, they're just drawn by the text editor he's using in order to indicate that there is a space.

Comment: @noidea : If you want to remove preceding or following spaces you could call `.Trim()` or `.TrimEnd()` on every string.

Comment: @VisualVincent sorry, I see that now as I'm re-reading it.

Comment: @MichaelZ. : We all misread sometimes. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent But the beginning of the string doesn't have 12 chars, it as "example" and two line breakers..

Comment: And, what is your point?

Comment: I can't use Trim in every string.. The answer Sage provided seems suitable, but i can't use it before removing the introduction of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the **GetOPString**() function to return a string with your items in it (DEFAULT","EX W SPACE","POTATO" and "HELP PLS") with a padding of 12 characters. That function you do not need because your source string is already built like that.

I used the following logic

1. Split source string into lines
2. If there is a word with no space in front (EXAMPLE), It is some sort of title so I ignore it (you didn't want it in the final result)
3. Trim word to remove all spaces and starting ">" character if found

See the example below.

You can tweak it according to your need.

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim Rawstring As String = GetOPString("DEFAULT","EX W SPACE","POTATO",">HELP PLS")
    Dim SEPARATED As List(Of String) = GetListItems(Rawstring)

    For Each Item As String In SEPARATED
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(Item)
    Next
End Sub



  ''' <summary>
''' Get a list of string by dividing Rawstring into 12 chars sequence. 
''' Any space is trimmed and leading > character (if found) is removed.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="RawString"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Private Function GetListItems(RawString As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim Output As New List(Of String)

    For Each item In RawString.Split(vbCr)
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item) Then Continue For

        Dim AssumeTitle As Boolean = Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item(0))
        If AssumeTitle Then Continue For 'EXAMPLE is the title and we do not want it in the checkbox

        item = item.Trim.TrimStart(">"c)
        Output.Add(item)

    Next



    Return Output
End Function

''' <summary>
''' I used this function only to return the string you have in your post, 
''' which is, words to be separated in 12 characters sequences.
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Private Function GetOPString(ByVal ParamArray Words As String()) As String
    Dim Output As New Text.StringBuilder
    Output.AppendLine("EXAMPLE")
    Output.AppendLine()

    For Each Item As String In Words
        Output.Append(vbTab)
        If Not Item.StartsWith(">") Then
            Output.Append(" ")
        End If
        Output.AppendLine(Item.PadRight(12))
    Next

    Return Output.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. What about the beggining of sentence? Everything in the image is the output .. "Example" and the linebreakers as well.

Comment: See my edited answer. This will work with the exact string you provided.

Comment: Your mention of the 12 characters was finally not deterministic. I used the line breaks to get a list of result and ignored "titles" or item that were at the start of the line (no spaces).

Comment: Pretty good! It was hard to understand how, but i got there already ! Thank you