# Remove Scriptlet <%some text here%> tags from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

How Can we remove all the scriptlet tags i.e. **<%** *some text here* **%>** from a string. Example string: `this is a string <% test text %> containing scriptlet tags <% test text %> how to remove all the tags with the text inside.`

Comment: you want to remove all `<%some_text%>` from a string?

Comment: @GeomanYabes ,Yes need to remove all tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this. The [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method will do this for you.

```
var text = "<% test text %> containing scriptlet tags <% test text %> how to remove all the tags with the text inside.";
var pattern = "<%[^>]*%>";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var result = regex.Replace(text, string.Empty);
```

This will result in

> containing scriptlet tags  how to remove all the tags with the text inside.

If you want to test and/or learn more about regular expressions have a look at [regexr](http://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this regex:

`<%[^%>]*%>`

**Explanation:**
Regex finds all string that starts with `<%` and followed by (any character except for `%>`) and ends with `%>`.

Use it like this:

`string result = new Regex("<%[^%>]*%>").Replace(sampleStr, string.Empty);`

**Tests:**

```
sample1: "This is a string <%with_tag%> and tag <%new_tag%>."
result1: "This is a string  and tag ."

sample2: "This is a string <%with_tag%>tag%> and tag <%new_tag%>."
result2: "This is a string tag%> and tag ."
```

Also, please note that this does not clear up the extra `<space>` especially when there are lots of consecutive tags.

```
sampleStr: "This is a string <%with_tag%>tag%> and <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%>tag <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%>."
result: "This is a string tag%> and     tag      ."
```

on which you can use another Regex (if performance really shouldn't matter):

`result = new Regex("\s{2,}").Replace(result, " ");`

so:

```
string sampleStr = "This is a string <%with_tag%>tag%> and <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%> <%new_tag%>tag <%new_tag%>.";
string result = new Regex("<%[^%>]*%>").Replace(sampleStr, string.Empty);
result = new Regex("\s{2,}").Replace(result, " ");
```

If you consider performance, you should check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279859/how-to-replace-multiple-white-spaces-with-one-white-space).