# PHP limit text to x number of words, or first paragraph, whichever is shorter

Tags: php, html, magento

I have something like the following string (product description) outputted from a system (Magento):

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque
>   sit amet leo ut metus commodo lacinia non sit amet lorem. Nam laoreet
>   blandit eros quis rhoncus. Curabitur mi dolor, gravida vel lacinia in,
>   pretium ut felis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
>   parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
> Donec mollis vitae dolor eu
>   viverra. Phasellus congue tortor ante, vel efficitur massa consectetur
>   eu. Proin lacus nibh, vestibulum eu lectus sit amet, porttitor aliquet
>   lorem. Ut tristique consectetur nulla in scelerisque. Mauris semper
>   massa eu nisi rutrum consequat. Pellentesque vestibulum lacinia
>   tellus, quis imperdiet orci hendrerit nec.

however I would like to get just the first x number of words, or up to the first paragraph (unfortunately the system we're using creates paragraphs by using double `<br><br>` tags).

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965235/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-to-the-first-20-words-in-php) answer to create the following:

```
echo preg_replace( '/((\w+\W*){'.$numberOfWords.'}(\w+))(.*)/', '${1}', $processor->filter($description) );
```

However that does not account for paragraphs. I tried working an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834256/need-regex-to-return-first-paragraph-or-first-n-words) into the above, unfortunately I couldn't get this to work (just returned the full untruncated string - likely down to my lack of regex ability!) Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you need the shortest between (the first paragraph) VS (n words), you have to take the first paragraph, then limit it by n words. Something like:

```
$first_p = preg_replace(
    '/^(.*?)<br><br>.*$/s', // Not tested, but it should be something like that
    '\\1', 
    $processor->filter($description)
);
```

Now `$first_p` contains your first paragraph. You just need to display the first n words of this paragraph:

```
echo preg_replace( '/((\w+\W*){'.$numberOfWords.'}(\w+))(.*)/', '${1}', $first_p );
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, this is very close, though at the end of the paragraph, it's stripped out the ending '.'

Comment: what if you display only `$first_p` ? I Maybe it's the second part (your original regex)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by simply doing the following:

```
$descriptionStripped =   preg_replace( '/((\w+\W*){'.$numberOfWords.'}(\w+))(.*)/', '${1}', $processor->filter($description) );
$descriptionFirstPara = explode("<br><br>", $descriptionStripped);
echo $descriptionFirstPara[0];
```